# NSTimer Failing to Stop?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

Sorry this is a repeat question, but I have tried all the solutions I could find without success.

Anyway, here is my problem, specifically. I have the following code where I start a timer on a long press gesture, then stop it when that gesture is cancelled or when the action is complete.

```
-(void)photoLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)press
{
    NSTimer *timer = nil;

    if (press.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        //Start timer
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(photoLongPressTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
    if (press.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;
    }
}

-(void)photoLongPressTimer:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    DAProgressOverlayView *progress = (DAProgressOverlayView *)[self.view viewWithTag:kTagPhotoDeleteProgressIndicator];

    progress.progress += 0.08;

    if (progress.progress == 1)
    {
        [self deletePhotoSelection];
        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;
    }
}
```

The timer stops when invalidated in the `photoLongPressTimer` method, but not if the gesture stops in the `photoLongPress` method. Why might this be? I'm stumped.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store `timer` in an instance variable so that you can refer to it later. It works in `photoLongPressTimer:` because the timer is passed as a parameter but in `photoLongPress:` it is nil because you haven't just created it and it's a local reference.

Add a property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSTimer *timer;
```

Store the new timer into it:

```
self.timer = [NSTimer schedu...
```

Invalidate and nil the property:

```
[self.timer invalidate];
self.timer = nil;
```

Comment: This works great. I am curious though, why would a local variable not work when there (at leafs at first appearence) seems to be a reference to the original object?

Comment: You have the reference when you initially create the timer but each time the gesture changes the method is called again a new local reference is created (and set to nil).

Answer (score 2):

```
NSTimer *timer = nil;
```

This line only creates a local variable.
You must make a property for the timer.
Put this in your **.h** file.

```
@property (strong) NSTimer *timer;
```

---

Then use the code here

```
-(void)photoLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)press
{    
    if (press.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        //Start timer
        self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(photoLongPressTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
    if (press.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        [self.timer invalidate];
        self.timer = nil;
    }
}

-(void)photoLongPressTimer:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    DAProgressOverlayView *progress = (DAProgressOverlayView *)[self.view viewWithTag:kTagPhotoDeleteProgressIndicator];

    progress.progress += 0.08;

    if (progress.progress == 1)
    {
        [self deletePhotoSelection];
        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with   `NSTimer *timer = nil;`
 in `-(void)photoLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)press`
 method.

remove `NSTimer *timer = nil;` from this method and store instance of NSTimer.

Comment: Would be helpful to elaborate on which manner to store the instance since technically the poster is storing an instance, albeit temporarily.